# What does "%.*s" mean in printf?

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

I got a code snippet in which there is a

```
printf("%.*s\n")
```

what does the `%.*s` mean?

Comment: Without additional arguments, that is not a valid `printf` call.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

You can use an asterisk (`*`) to pass the width specifier/precision to [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html), rather than hard coding it into the format string, i.e.

```
void f(const char *str, int str_len)
{
  printf("%.*s\n", str_len, str);
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that the `str_len` argument must have type `int` (or narrower integral type, which would be promoted to `int`). It would be a bug to pass `long`, `size_t`, etc.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the likely purpose of this code, especially when used with `%s`, is to print a sub-string of the original string. In this use case, `str` would point to somewhere inside the original string (possibly at the beginning), and `str_len` will specify the length of the sub-string that should be printed.

Comment: By specifying a length, we can get around printing (or sprintf) 'ing a string which has no null terminator, for example a string which is input from any stream or file based source. Which is far more often the use case I have encountered, than merely print prettines.

Answer (score 50):

More detailed [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

> integer value or `*` that specifies minimum field width. The result is padded with space characters (by default), if required, on the left when right-justified, or on the right if left-justified. In the case when * is used, the width is specified by an additional argument of type int. If the value of the argument is negative, it results with the - flag specified and positive field width. (Note: This is the minimum width: The value is never truncated.)
>
> `.` followed by integer number or *, or neither that specifies precision
>   of the conversion. In the case when * is used, the precision is
>   specified by an additional argument of type int. If the value of this
>   argument is negative, it is ignored. If neither a number nor * is
>   used, the precision is taken as zero. See the table below for exact
>   effects of precision.

So if we try both conversion specification

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int precision = 8;
    int biggerPrecision = 16;
    const char *greetings = "Hello world";

    printf("|%.8s|\n", greetings);
    printf("|%.*s|\n", precision , greetings);
    printf("|%16s|\n", greetings);
    printf("|%*s|\n", biggerPrecision , greetings);

    return 0;
}
```

we get the output:

```
|Hello wo|
|Hello wo|
|     Hello world|
|     Hello world|
```

Comment: From the docs, the major difference between '%.*s' and '%*s' seems to be that the former ignore negative values for precision while the later takes in into consideration to apply the appropriate justification.

Comment: You could also add `printf("|%.*s|\n", biggerPrecision , greetings);`

Answer (score 13):

I don't think the code above is correct but (according to this description of [`printf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)) the `.*` means

> The width is not specified in the format string, but as an additional integer value argument preceding the argument that has to be formatted.'

So it's a string with a passable width as an argument.

Comment: I've added the URL cross-reference so you can avoid charges of plagiarism.  Of course, the correct quote says "The _precision_ is not …" rather than "The _width_ is not…".

Comment: As @MattMcNabb pointed out, every reference to that page must highlight that “*an integer value*” is exactly `int` (or a subset of it) — not just any integral value like more intuitive `size_t` or its possible aliases, like `std::string::size_type`. This is even more confusing, taking into account that the referenced page mentions `size_t` as one of supported type specifiers.

Answer (score 11):

See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

> `.*`  The precision is not specified in the format string, but as an additional integer value argument preceding the argument that has to be formatted.
>
> `s`   String of characters