# What does %.*s represent on printf?

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what does “%.*s” mean in printf in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899119/what-does-s-mean-in-printf-in-c)

I know this question has for sure been asked elsewhere, but searching "%.*s" yields nothing meaningful on SO. Could someone please explain the following line to me?

`printf("%.*s", len, buffer);`

Comment: From a reference on `printf`, *(optional) . followed by integer number or * that specifies precision of the conversion. In the case when * is used, the precision is specified by an additional argument of type int.*

Comment: *::peaks at pap42's tags::* Ah...try `man 3 printf`. One of the nice things about unix is having documentation for both the c standard library and the OS's APIs accessible at the command line. Question for the student: what does the 3 mean and why is it necessary?

Comment: I assume you meant to put the `*` in your example code.

Comment: Indeed it's a duplicate; as I said, I could not find anything meaningful on SO using the search tool. I will vote for the deletion of the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It limits the output to at most `len` characters.  The `.` starts the 'precision'; the `*` says 'use an `int` from the argument list to determine the precision'.  Note that the 'string' (`buffer`) does not even have to be null terminated if it is longer than `len`.

All this is easily found in the manual page for [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html).

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice table [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) showing what all the different format specifiers can do for you. For your example, let's say you have a buffer and a length defined as:

```
char buf[] = "Hello World";
len = 5;
```

You can use `%.*s` to print a portion of the full string:

```
printf("%.*s", len, buffer);
```

This outputs `Hello` the first 5 (1 based) characters in this case. Note this is the same as:

```
printf("%.5s", buffer);
```