# what "%.*s" means in the asprintf?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what does “%.*s” mean in printf in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899119/what-does-s-mean-in-printf-in-c)

I have found the following line :

```
asprintf(&c, "%s%.*s", *msg_in, size * rxed, buffer)
```

And I want to know the meaning of `%.*s`

Comment: Did you try the documentation?

Comment: I didn't know the answer, but it took about a minute to find it with Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `%.*s` format means "print a string using a field width of *n* characters, where *n* is read from the next argument".

So here, it prints `buffer` with a width of `size * rxed` characters. (padding with spaces if necessary)

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend reading the manual...

`.*` in a format string means:

> the precision is not specified in the format string, but as an additional integer value argument preceding the argument that has to be formatted.

Details can be seen [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

So you didn't give any details, but if the result of: `size * rxed` was 5, then you could do this:

```
asprintf(&c, "%s%.*s", *msg_in, size * rxed, buffer)
```

or

```
asprintf(&c, "%s%5s", *msg_in, buffer)
```

to the same effect.