# What's the type of the "precision" specifier for printf?

Tags: c++, c, printf, format-specifiers

Suppose I use the following `printf()` specifier string:

```
printf("%.*s", length, str);
```

which asks `printf()` to [print the first `length` characters in `str`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7899144/57428). The question is which type `length` has? I only see brief mentions of *integer number* in the documentation.

So it looks like it is `int`. Then it looks like I cannot use the following code when a string is very long:

```
const char* startOfString = ...    
const char* middleOfString = ...
printf("%.*s", (int)( middleOfString - startOfString ), startOfString);
```

It looks like I cannot output more than `INT_MAX` characters this way.

So which type is *precision*? Is it `int` or is it `size_t` or anything else?

Comment: If by "the documentation", you mean "cplusplus.com", I suggest you find a better default documentation source. I'd start with the manpage (`man fprintf`) on a unix-like system ("the next argument... which must be of type int"). If you're on Windows, you can read [manpages online](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3.html). There's also http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf . (" the precision is specified by an additional argument of type int")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an `int`, and you cannot print more than `INT_MAX` characters that way.

From the C standard, § 7.21.6.1, para. 5:

> a field width, or precision, or both, may be indicated by an asterisk. In
>   this case, an `int` argument supplies the field width or precision.