# Novice Query on C strings Jsmn jason parser

Tags: c, json, jsmn

I have started by programming with Golang, and things looked easy.Then I stumbled on JSON parser of C ([JSMN](https://github.com/zserge/jsmn)) so that I can try CGO.

Here's the code lines ([11](https://github.com/zserge/jsmn/blob/732d283ee9a2e5c34c52af0e044850576888ab09/example/simple.c#L11) and [46](https://github.com/zserge/jsmn/blob/732d283ee9a2e5c34c52af0e044850576888ab09/example/simple.c#L46)) from this [example](https://github.com/zserge/jsmn/blob/master/example/simple.c):

```
static const char *JSON_STRING =
    "{\"user\": \"johndoe\", \"admin\": false, \"uid\": 1000,\n  "
    "\"groups\": [\"users\", \"wheel\", \"audio\", \"video\"]}";

printf("- User: %.*s\n", t[i+1].end-t[i+1].start, JSON_STRING + t[i+1].start);
```

This gives me result:

> "- User: johndoe"

I am new to C. I want to get the value **"johndoe"** into a variable. I tried below code its giving me `NULL`:

```
int c = 0;
char sub[1000];
while (c < (t[i+1].end-t[i+1].start) ) {
    sub[c] = JSON_STRING[t[i+1].start+c-1];
    c++;
}
sub[c] = '\0';
```

Output:

> "-User: null "

How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried printing the assignment variable (`JSON_STRING[t[i+1].start+c-1]`) for few values of `c` and the condition variable (`t[i+1].end-t[i+1].start`) separately to check what it holds? PLUS what do you mean by - "giving me NULL"?

Comment: `JSON_STRING` looks like a constant and you are trying to access `JSON_STRING[t[i+1].start+c-1]´

Comment: Have a look at `sprintf` and `snprintf` in [printf(3) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)

Comment: Added details about NULL and JSON-STRING above

Comment: Which code do you use to print `sub`?

Comment: "*`... = JSON_STRING[t[i+1].start+c-1];`*": Why the `-1`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strncpy()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) to copy the required string in a separate variable as you already know the length and the starting point of the string i.e.:

```
t[i+1].end - t[i+1].start     // length of the string to copy
JSON_STRING + t[i+1].start    // starting point from where to start copying
```

For example:

```
const char*  strStart  = JSON_STRING + t[i+1].start;
const size_t strLength = t[i+1].end - t[i+1].start;

const size_t length = 8;      // required to store "johndoe"
char strCopy[ length ] = { 0 };

strncpy( strCopy, strStart, strLength );
// You might need to null terminate your string
// depending upon your specific use case.
```

---

JSMN parser stores the start and end positions of tokens. The user of the library is required to make copies as and when required using these positions.

`%.*s` format specifier in `printf()` takes field width (string length to be printed) preceding the actual C-style string as arguments. For more details, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899119/what-does-s-mean-in-printf).