# Bash prompt with the last exit code

Tags: linux, bash, prompt

I've been trying to customize my Bash prompt so that it will look like

```
[feralin@localhost ~]$ _
```

with colors. I managed to get constant colors (the same colors every time I see the prompt), but I want the username ('feralin') to appear red, instead of green, if the last command had a nonzero exit status. I came up with:

```
\e[1;33m[$(if [[ $? == 0  ]]; then echo "\e[0;31m"; else echo "\e[0;32m"; fi)\u\e[m@\e[1;34m\h \e[0;35m\W\e[1;33m]$ \e[m
```

However, from my observations, the `$(if ...; fi)` seems to be evaluated once, when the `.bashrc` is run, and the result is substituted forever after. This makes the name always green, even if the last exit code is nonzero (as in, `echo $?`). Is this what is happening? Or is it simply something else wrong with my prompt? Long question short, **how do I get my prompt to use the last exit code?**

Comment: I've never succeeded at something like that either; what I have done, however, is put ${?#0} into the prompt which prints the numeric exit status if and only if it's non-zero.

Comment: It works as is. You just have reversed green and red.

Comment: Shameless plug for [prompt.gem](https://bitbucket.org/dimo414/prompt.gem) which provides an extensible prompt that includes both the exit code and duration of the previous command.

Comment: Re: "evaluated once, when the `.bashrc` is run" -- that means you're putting the wrong kinds of quotes around it when assigning to `PS1`. Needs to be single, not double. If that doesn't help, then you're getting `$?` reset by something else that's running before your prompt is printed; `set -x` will enable tracking such commands down.

Comment: Works for me too, except green and red reversed. Are you doing `PS1='...'` with single quotes? Do `echo $PS1` to verify it's being set properly.

Comment: @wisbucky I haven't used this bash prompt in several years, so unfortunately I cannot verify anything about it anymore...

Comment: has bash5 changed anything? there are so many broken suggestions out there...

Answer (score 156, accepted):

As you are starting to border on a complex [PS1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command_prompt), you might consider using `PROMPT_COMMAND`. With this, you set it to a function, and it will be run after each command to generate the prompt.

You could try the following in your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=__prompt_command    # Function to generate PS1 after CMDs

__prompt_command() {
    local EXIT="$?"                # This needs to be first
    PS1=""

    local RCol='\[\e[0m\]'

    local Red='\[\e[0;31m\]'
    local Gre='\[\e[0;32m\]'
    local BYel='\[\e[1;33m\]'
    local BBlu='\[\e[1;34m\]'
    local Pur='\[\e[0;35m\]'

    if [ $EXIT != 0 ]; then
        PS1+="${Red}\u${RCol}"        # Add red if exit code non 0
    else
        PS1+="${Gre}\u${RCol}"
    fi

    PS1+="${RCol}@${BBlu}\h ${Pur}\W${BYel}$ ${RCol}"
}
```

This should do what it sounds like you want. Take a look a my *bashrc*'s [sub file](https://github.com/demure/dotfiles/blob/master/subbash/prompt) if you want to see all the things I do with my `__prompt_command` function.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know about PROMPT_COMMAND. I'll try it now.

Comment: All right, it works! I just changed it a little to include the [...] delimeters before the "$ ". Other than that, it was perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it does what you want. You can also trash the color vars if you want, but using them makes it so much more readable.

Comment: @demure - your `PROMPT_COMMAND` is no longer in your `.bashrc` file.  Also, it doesn't appear that `$HOME/.subbash` is in your github repo.  I had to go back 3-4 history versions in your .bashrc to see its former contents.

Comment: One thing to note is that PROMPT_COMMAND can introduce terminal lag on boxes with significant load. This can cause issues with random space characters being inserted whilst holding down <enter>. Because of this, I chose to only include exit status via `PS1` (eg: `${?##0}`)

Comment: I'd suggest using a variable name with at least one lower-case character for `EXIT`, as a forward compatibility practice. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, fourth paragraph -- the namespace of all-caps names is used for variables with meaning to the system or shell; sticking to lowercase names prevents overwriting an environment variable or shell-builtin variable when trying only to assign a shell variable. Granted, with a local declaration that overwrite is temporary, which makes it less of an issue than usual here, but still not ideal.

Comment: On mac you need `PROMPT_COMMAND="__prompt_command; ${PROMPT_COMMAND}"` to enable opening a new tab / window in the current working directory still works. `PROMPT_COMMAND=update_terminal_cwd` by default, which logs the cwd.

Comment: Bash variable `PIPESTATUS` provides more information about the last executed command or pipe. `${PIPESTATUS[@]}` will be a string of zeroes like `0 0 0` in case all commands were executed correctly, otherwise it will have non zeroes like `0 127 1`. One can check for success with `if $(echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]} | grep -qEe '^0( 0)*$'); then echo "good"; else echo "bad"; fi`.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without breaking updating the PS1 by other programs, e.g, activation of python virtualenv?

Comment: BTW: I got this working with `if [ ! -z "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ]; then
        PS1+=" (${VIRTUAL_ENV##*/})"
    fi`

Comment: I'm curious why this retains the exit code if I just hit RET on an empty prompt. For example, if I hit ^C the prompt turns red and remains that way until I actually run some command with exit code 0.

Comment: @Jani, I presume that the reason is that the `$?` variable retains the value of the _last executed command_. Pressing Ctrl+C or Enter does not run any command.

Comment: Is it possible to do it on git bash for Windows? I tried updating `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile.d\git-prompt.sh`, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 26):

If you don't want to use the prompt command there are two things you need to take into account:

1. getting the value of `$?` before anything else. Otherwise it'll be overridden.
2. escaping all the `$`'s in the PS1 (so it's not evaluated when you assign it)

**Working example using a variable**

```
PS1="\$(VALU="\$?" ; echo \$VALU ; date ; if [ \$VALU == 0 ]; then echo zero; else echo nonzero; fi) "
```

**Working example without a variable**

Here the *if* needs to be the first thing, before any command that would override the `$?`.

```
PS1="\$(if [ \$? == 0 ]; then echo zero; else echo nonzero; fi) "
```

Notice how the `\$()` is escaped so it's not executed right away, but each time PS1 is used. Also all the uses of `\$?`.

Comment: This is so amazingly awesome! I've been an old dirty bashtard since 1995 and it's never occurred to me to use command substitution in my PS1. Thank you.

Comment: Though I do prefer simple ternary notation: `export PS1="\$([ \$? == 0 ] && echo ✅ || echo ⚠️ ) \h:\W \u\n\$ "`

Comment: This is cool and i'm currently editing my .bashrc file to incorporate.
Tiny nit: "-eq" instead of "==" (and "=" instead of "==").

Comment: This solution is particularly interesting when using tools like python's `virtualenv` which prefix `PS1` variable with information when activated. Using `PROMPT_COMMAND` would not work!

Comment: It seems if you use `\${PIPESTATUS[-1]}` you can get the exit status of the last command even if it isn't the first thing in your `PS1`.

Comment: We can make the whole PS1 variable inside single quote so escaping is not needed.

Answer (score 11):

Compact solution:

```
PS1='... $(code=${?##0};echo ${code:+[error: ${code}]})'
```

This approach does not require `PROMPT_COMMAND` (apparently this can be slower sometimes) and prints `[error: <code>]` if the exit code is non-zero, and nothing if it's zero:

```
... > false
... [error: 1]> true
... >
```

Change the `[error: ${code}]` part depending on your liking, with `${code}` being the non-zero code to print.

Note the use of `'` to ensure the inline `$()` shell gets executed when PS1 is evaluated later, not when the shell is started.

As bonus, you can make it colorful in red by adding `\e[01;31m` in front and `\e[00m` after to reset:

```
PS1='... \e[01;31m$(code=${?##0};echo ${code:+[error: ${code}]})\e[00m'
```

--

How it works:

- it uses [bash parameter substitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)
- first, the `${?##0}` will read the exit code `$?` of the previous command
- the `##` will remove any `0` pattern from the beginning, effectively making a `0` result an empty var (thanks [@blaskovicz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/626810/blaskovicz) for the trick)
- we assign this to a temporary `code` variable as we need to do another substitution, and they can't be nested
- the `${code:+REPLACEMENT}` will print the `REPLACEMENT` part only if the variable `code` is set (non-empty)
- this way we can add some text and brackets around it, and reference the variable again inline: `[error: ${code}]`

Comment: Thanks - I actually think this is the cleanest solution of all. I always end up selecting this when I want this behavior for a new environment. Personally, the red color and status if non-zero in itself suffices. To prepend space, `""` must be used: `PS1='\e[01;31m$(code=${?##0};echo "${code:+${code} }")\e[00m'"$PS1"`

Answer (score 9):

I wanted to keep default [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) colors, print the exact code, and only print it on failure:

```
# Show exit status on failure.
PROMPT_COMMAND=__prompt_command

__prompt_command() {
    local curr_exit="$?"

    local BRed='\[\e[0;91m\]'
    local RCol='\[\e[0m\]'

    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '

    if [ "$curr_exit" != 0 ]; then
        PS1="[${BRed}$curr_exit${RCol}]$PS1"
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The following provides a leading green check mark when the exit code is zero and a red cross in all other cases. The remainder is a standard colorized prompt.  The `printf` statements can be modified to present the two states that were originally requested.

```
PS1='$(if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then printf "\033[01;32m""\xE2\x9C\x93"; else printf "\033[01;31m""\xE2\x9C\x95"; fi) \[\e[00;32m\]\u@\h\[\e[00;30m\]:\[\e[01;33m\]\w\[\e[01;37m\]\$ '
```

Answer (score 1):

Improved [demure answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715103/bash-prompt-with-the-last-exit-code/16715681#16715681):

I think this is important because the exit status is not always 0 or 1.

```
if [ $EXIT != 0 ]; then
    PS1+="${Red}${EXIT}:\u${RCol}"      # Add red if exit code != 0
else
    PS1+="${Gre}${EXIT}:\u${RCol}"      # Also displays exit status
fi
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't quoting the expansion? If a user with this PROMPT_COMMAND set `IFS=0`, then this would become `if [ != 0 ]` on expansion (with a zero exit code, of course); making it `if [ "$EXIT" != 0 ]` will avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

Why didn't I think about that myself? I found this very interesting and added this feature to my '[info-bar](https://github.com/vaniacer/info-bar)' project. Eyes will turn red if the last command failed.

```
#!/bin/bash
eyes=(O o ∘ ◦ ⍤ ⍥) en=${#eyes[@]} mouth='_'
face () { # gen random face
    [[ $error -gt 0 ]] && ecolor=$RED || ecolor=$YLW
    if [[ $1 ]]; then printf "${eyes[$[RANDOM%en]]}$mouth${eyes[$[RANDOM%en]]}"
                 else printf "$ecolor${eyes[$[RANDOM%en]]}$YLW$mouth$ecolor${eyes[$[RANDOM%en]]}$DEF"
    fi
}
info () { error=$?
    [[ -d .git ]] && {  # If in git project folder add git status to info bar output
        git_clr=('GIT' $(git -c color.ui=always status -sb)) # Colored output 4 info
        git_tst=('GIT' $(git                    status -sb)) # Simple  output 4 test
    }
    printf -v line "%${COLUMNS}s"                            # Set border length
    date=$(printf "%(%a %d %b %T)T")                         # Date & time 4 test
    test=" O_o $PWD  ${git_tst[*]} $date o_O "               # Test string
    step=$[$COLUMNS-${#test}]; [[ $step -lt 0 ]] && step=0   # Count spaces
    line="$GRN${line// /-}$DEF\n"                            # Create lines
    home="$BLD$BLU$PWD$DEF"                                  # Home dir info
    date="$DIM$date$DEF"                                     # Colored date & time
           #------+-----+-------+--------+-------------+-----+-------+--------+
           # Line | O_o |homedir| Spaces | Git  status | Date|  o_O  |  Line  |
           #------+-----+-------+--------+-------------+-----+-------+--------+
    printf "$line $(face) $home %${step}s ${git_clr[*]} $date $(face) \n$line" # Final info string
}
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\n$(info)\n$ '
case "$TERM" in xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)} $(face 1) \w\a\]$PS1";;
esac
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the original prompt format (not just colors),
you could append following to the end of file `~/.bashrc`:

```sh
PS1_ORIG=$PS1 # original primary prompt value
PROMPT_COMMAND=__update_prompt # Function to be re-evaluated after each command is executed
__update_prompt() {
    local PREVIOUS_EXIT_CODE="$?"
    if [ $PREVIOUS_EXIT_CODE != 0 ]; then
        local RedCol='\[\e[0;31m\]'
        local ResetCol='\[\e[0m\]'
        local replacement="${RedCol}\u${ResetCol}"
    
        # Replace username color
        PS1=${PS1_ORIG//]\\u/]$replacement}
        ## Alternative: keep same colors, append exit code
        #PS1="$PS1_ORIG[${RedCol}error=$PREVIOUS_EXIT_CODE${ResetCol}]$ "
    else
        PS1=$PS1_ORIG
    fi
}
```

See also the comment about the alternative approach that preserves username color and just appends an error code in red to the end of the original prompt format.

Comment: this solution is somewhat based on ideas/solutions of demure and Velkan (but preserves original format and colors)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a similar result to *include a  colored (non-zero) exit code* in a prompt, without using subshells in the prompt nor prompt_command.

You color the exit code portion of the prompt, while having it only appear when non-zero.

[image: prompt lines color variations with zero & non-zero exit codes]

Core `2$` section of the prompt: `\\[\\033[0;31;4m\\]\${?#0}\\[\\033[0;33m\\]\$ \\[\\033[0m\\]`

Key elements:

- return code, if not `0`: `\${?#0}` (specificly "removes prefix of 0")
- change color without adding to calculated prompt-width: `\\[\\033[0;31m\\]`

  - `\\[` - begin block
  - `\\033` - treat as 0-width, in readline calculations for cmdline editing
  - `[0;31;4m` - escape code, change color, red fg, underline
  - `\\]` - end block

Components:

- `\\[\\033[0;31;4m\\]` - set color 0;31m fg red, underline
- `\${?#0}` - display non-zero status (by removing 0 prefix)
- `\\[\\033[0;33m\\]` - set color 0;33m fg yellow
- `\$`  - `$` or `#` on EUID
- `\\[\\033[0m\\]` - reset color

The full PS1 I use (on one host):

`declare -x PS1="\\[\\033[0;35m\\]\\h\\[\\033[1;37m\\] \\[\\033[0;37m\\]\\w \\[\\033[0;33m\\]\\[\\033[0;31;4m\\]\${?#0}\\[\\033[0;33m\\]\$ \\[\\033[0m\\]"`

Note: this addresses a natural extension to this question, in a more enduring way then a comment.

Answer (score 0):

### Bash

```bash
function my_prompt {
    local retval=$?
    local field1='\u@\h'
    local field2='\w'
    local field3='$([ $SHLVL -gt 1 ] && echo \ shlvl:$SHLVL)$([ \j -gt 0 ] && echo \ jobs:\j)'"$([ ${retval} -ne 0 ] && echo \ exit:$retval)"
    local field4='\$'

    PS1=$'\n'"\e[0;35m${field1}\e[m \e[0;34m${field2}\e[m\e[0;31m${field3}\e[m"$'\n'"\[\e[0;36m\]${field4}\[\e[m\] "


}

PROMPT_COMMAND="my_prompt; ${PROMPT_COMMAND}"
```

### Zsh

```bash
PROMPT=$'\n''%F{magenta}%n@%m%f %F{blue}%~%f%F{red}%(2L. shlvl:%L.)%(1j. jobs:%j.)%(?.. exit:%?)%f'$'\n''%F{cyan}%(!.#.$)%f '
```

### Images of prompt

[image: image of prompt]
[image: image of prompt]