# How to use function on git-prompt on Git Bash for Windows?

Tags: windows, bash, git, terminal, windows-terminal

I want to use the last exit code to customize my bash prompt. So following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715103/bash-prompt-with-last-exit-code) I should add `$?` inside a function:

```sh
PROMPT_COMMAND=__prompt_command

__prompt_command() {
    local EXIT="$?"
    ...
```

I tried many times, but whenever I add a function on my `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile.d\git-prompt.sh` file, Git Bash can't run this file, and it doesn't use it.

Is there a way to use a function on `git-prompt.sh` on Git Bash for Windows, or another approach to use the last exit code to customize the bash prompt?

Comment: Can't you put this in your `~/.bashrc`? It might work if you put it in your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: @ShaneBishop Since the prompt configuration is written in `git-prompt.sh`, I think that writing into `~/.bashrc` won't work, since it isn't used by the prompt

Comment: I just tested using `~/.bashrc` and it works. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these instructions to configure your git-bash prompt.

First, open git-bash, and `cd` to your `~` directory.

Using `vim` or `nano`, edit your `~/.bash_profile` file to contain the following two lines:

```sh
test -f ~/.profile && . ~/.profile
test -f ~/.bashrc && . ~/.bashrc
```

Then create a `~/.bashrc` file and add your custom prompt command function in this file:

```sh
PROMPT_COMMAND=__prompt_command

__prompt_command() {
    local EXIT="$?"
    # The rest of your code here
}
```

Make sure your changes saved correctly for both your `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc` files.

Open a new git-bash window. Assuming you have no bugs in your `__prompt_command()` function, your custom prompt should display properly.

If you quickly want to test your prompt, you can instead just run `source ~/.bashrc` in your current git-bash window rather than launching a second one.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Just for reference: to do an `if` I needed to write `if [[ $? -gt 0 ]];`