# Check if the previous command was "valid"

Tags: bash

I have a function defined in `.bashrc` that displays whether or not the previous command completed successfully or not (simplified from [the full version](https://gist.github.com/IQAndreas/5d22728244b6cbcf59b4)):

```
function previous_command_status()
{
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Command successful"
    else
        echo "Command failed with exit code $exit_code"
    fi
}

PROMPT_COMMAND="previous_command_status"
```

The problem is, `Command successful` gets displayed immediately when I start the prompt, even if I haven't "officially" run any commands yet. Second (and for the same reason), the script displays `Command successful` (or the output of the last "real" command) even if all I did was hit the return button without actually executing a command ([example output](https://gist.github.com/IQAndreas/2d0c2e0bfc9a5a0c1dc1)).

How I can get the script to only display the message if a command was actually run?

Comment: I've seen some prompts that show the exit code if it is different than zero, but shows nothing if it is zero. In other words, it never prints "Command successful", as that is implied. It is a hacky workaround, but works well.

Comment: Feel free to give suggestions for a more descriptive question title, I couldn't come up with anything better.

Comment: @DenilsonSá That still doesn't solve the problem if the previous command gave an error code. You get this funny business: https://gist.github.com/IQAndreas/2d0c2e0bfc9a5a0c1dc1#file-gistfile1-sh-L12-L15 (see lines 12 through 15)

Comment: I don't have suggestions, I already believe this is a good and well-written question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946873/include-non-0-exit-codes-in-the-subsequent-bash-prompt

Comment: What's the shell you're using? This works for me with no errors.

Comment: @DenilsonSá Sadly, none of the answers in the question you linked to solve the problem. If I only wanted to output an error on a non-zero exit code, all I need to do is remove line 4 of the function (or use `if [ $? -ne 0 ];`)

Comment: @JohnB After running the command in the question, just [hit newline a few times and notice the superfluous messages](https://gist.github.com/IQAndreas/2d0c2e0bfc9a5a0c1dc1) even though you technically didn't execute anything that returns an error code.

Comment: Oh, it works for me because I didn't include the setting of `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

Comment: Would it work better if you did `if [ $1 -eq 0 ]; then` and for your `PROMPT_COMMAND="previous_command_status $?"`. I haven't tested, but it seems like you need to pass the result of the previous command as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by others it's no need to display so long a message in the prompt. The following is the `Bash` prompt I'm using:

[image: The screenshot]

As you can see the exit value in the prompt becomes RED when it's non-zero so you can easily know that the command just failed. And if the command is killed by a signal the signal number and name will also be displayed. In the above screenshot, `130:2:INT` means the last command exited with `130` (= 128 + 2) and it was killed by signal `2` (`SIGINT`).

The following is the code in `bashrc`:

```
function _PS1_command()
{
    local lastexit=$?
    local ESC=$'\033'

    (( lastexit )) && g_PS1_Qcolor="$ESC[1;31m" || g_PS1_Qcolor=

    g_PS1_signal=
    if (( lastexit > 128 )) && kill -l $(( lastexit - 128 )) > /dev/null
    then
        (( g_PS1_signal = lastexit - 128 ))
        g_PS1_signal="$g_PS1_signal:$( kill -l $g_PS1_signal )"
    fi

    return $lastexit
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=_PS1_command
PS1='[\w $g_PS1_Qcolor$?${g_PS1_signal:+:}$g_PS1_signal\e[0m] # '
```

Comment: I have seen it used on the same line elsewhere, but to me it is less clear when looking back on previous commands. For instance, it looks like `sleep 60` returned an exit code of `12`.

Comment: @IQAndreas: Not a big problem. You can use a multi-lined prompt like `PS1='Last exit: $g_PS1_Qcolor$?${g_PS1_signal:+:}$g_PS1_signal\e[0m\n[\w] # '`.

Comment: Still doesn't solve the actual problem in the question. Hitting the newline character, or running a command that doesn't return an exit code still keeps repeating the same exit code: (see https://gist.github.com/IQAndreas/2d0c2e0bfc9a5a0c1dc1)

Comment: @IQAndreas: I don't think that's possible with Bash. You can send the feature request to `bug-bash@gnu.org` .

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest ways to do this on the command line is with logical operators.

```
cmd && echo success # this will not print if cmd fails
cmd || echo command failed # this will only print if cmd fails
cmd1 && echo success || echo fail # this will print fail or success depending on outcome
```

Naturally you might want something more substantial in a script, but this is usually how I go about doing this.

Comment: The thing is, you aren't actually running the command inside the `PROMPT_COMMAND` function, all you have access to is the previous exit code.